# Does PHP automatically remove quotes?

Tags: php

Looking at the source code of my outputted HTML from a PHP script, I noticed almost none of my attribute values are quoted, even though I specifically quoted them in the PHP script.  I finally figured out that PHP seems to be automatically removing all the quotes if the value is just one word or number (no spaces).  I know this is still valid HTML5, but it still bugs me a little coming from an XML background.  Is there any way to disable that, or should I just suck it up and deal with it?  I've checked other sites I know that were built on PHP, and they output the quotes.

For example…
PHP source:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no">
```

Outputted HTML:

```
<meta name=viewport content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no">
```

Comment: where is the code man ?

Comment: Are you sure it's PHP removing the quotes? Add `header('Content-Type: text/plain');` to the very top of your script and check again.

Comment: PHP does not do that. May be an unwanted PHP extension is causing this.

Comment: I added example code.  This happens in both PHP code and the raw HTML around it.  Adding the header('Content-Type: text/plain'); does show all the quotes, but plain text is different from HTML, so it would make sense that it would do that.  I'm still relatively new to PHP and definitely haven't installed any extensions.

Comment: Can you post the PHP code responsible for outputting that meta tag? The question as it stands needs some more context. All you've got at the moment is two strings, so all that we can say is "yes, they are different".

Comment: This happens both inside and outside the PHP tags.  The code above, while in a PHP script file, wasn't part of a PHP block.  So no echo or print used.

Answer (score 0):

So the final issue was that my web host installed an Apache module ModPagespeed, and the solution is to add "ModPagespeed off" to the .htaccess file.  It was unrelated to PHP, just timed so they installed the module as I started learning PHP.